# rauth/flask: How to login via Twitter?

Tags: flask, twitter-oauth, rauth

The provided [example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/blob/master/examples/twitter-timeline-cli.py#L20) in rauth is using the PIN instead of the callback. I don't understand how this should work via web callback.

**1) Minor problem:**

According to twitter, if `oauth_callback` URL is passed in, then it should be used instead whatever entry is in the https://dev.twitter.com settings. However this doesn't seem to be true, if I dont set it to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/twitter/authorized` it would never get to that Url after a successful authorization.

```
app.add_url_rule('/twitter/login', view_func=views.twitter_login)  
app.add_url_rule('/twitter/authorized', 'twitter_authorized', view_func=views.twitter_authorized)

def twitter_login():
    request_token, request_token_secret = twitter.get_request_token()
    redirect_uri = url_for('twitter_authorized', _external=True)
    params = {'oauth_callback': redirect_uri, 'request_token':request_token}
    return redirect(twitter.get_authorize_url(**params))
```

**2) Major problem is here:**

I can see the request.args has both `['oauth_token']` and `['oauth_verifier']`.
But I don't understand how to use them to get the twitter session for obtaining user details such as picture and display name:

```
def twitter_authorized():
    tw_session = twitter.get_auth_session(request_token ??? , request_token_secret ???)
    resp = tw_session.get("account/verify_credentials.json", params={'format':'json'})    
    me = resp.json()
    user = User.get_or_create(...)

    if user:  
        login_user(user)            
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

If someone could shed some light on this, would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a working Twitter sign-in examples using Flask based on the Facebook example:

```
'''
    twitter
    -------

    A simple Flask demo app that shows how to login with Twitter via rauth.

    Please note: you must do `from twitter import db; db.create_all()` from
    the interpreter before running this example!
'''

from flask import (Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template, session,
                url_for)
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from rauth.service import OAuth1Service
from rauth.utils import parse_utf8_qsl


# Flask config
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///twitter.db'
SECRET_KEY = '\xfb\x12\xdf\xa1@i\xd6>V\xc0\xbb\x8fp\x16#Z\x0b\x81\xeb\x16'
DEBUG = True
TW_KEY = 'oZSbVzKCeyAZTDxw1RKog'
TW_SECRET = 'TuNoqA6NzEBS3Zrb8test7bxQfKTlBfLTXsZ8RaKAo'

# Flask setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# rauth OAuth 1.0 service wrapper
twitter = OAuth1Service(
    name='twitter',
    consumer_key=TW_KEY,
    consumer_secret=TW_SECRET,
    request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/')


# models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    fb_id = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __init__(self, username, fb_id):
        self.username = username
        self.fb_id = fb_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    @staticmethod
    def get_or_create(username, fb_id):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user is None:
            user = User(username, fb_id)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        return user


# views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/twitter/login')
def login():
    oauth_callback = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    params = {'oauth_callback': oauth_callback}

    r = twitter.get_raw_request_token(params=params)
    data = parse_utf8_qsl(r.content)

    session['twitter_oauth'] = (data['oauth_token'],
                                data['oauth_token_secret'])
    return redirect(twitter.get_authorize_url(data['oauth_token'], **params))


@app.route('/twitter/authorized')
def authorized():
    request_token, request_token_secret = session.pop('twitter_oauth')

    # check to make sure the user authorized the request
    if not 'oauth_token' in request.args:
        flash('You did not authorize the request')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    try:
        creds = {'request_token': request_token,
                'request_token_secret': request_token_secret}
        params = {'oauth_verifier': request.args['oauth_verifier']}
        sess = twitter.get_auth_session(params=params, **creds)
    except Exception, e:
        flash('There was a problem logging into Twitter: ' + str(e))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    verify = sess.get('account/verify_credentials.json',
                    params={'format':'json'}).json()

    User.get_or_create(verify['screen_name'], verify['id'])

    flash('Logged in as ' + verify['name'])
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Simply excellent. Both issues have been addressed. The key for problem one, was passing `oauth_callback` into get_raw_request_token(). I believe get_request_token() doesn't provide this.  The second problem was simply to save the tokens in the session for reuse. All in all its tricky without a running example. +1 Thank you very much.

Comment: @maxcountryman do you know why I would be receiving an error from twitter stating:

"Whoa there!
The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake."

I have made triple checked all of the parameters in my twitter variable, but that is not fixing my problem. Also, I have enabled 'Sign in with Twitter' in my account settings.

Comment: @user1876508 I'd be happy to look over your code if you emailed me.